# Arguments on censorship of the internet

Tags: ethics, social-ethics, internet

I'm looking for philosophical or ethical takes on the question of whether government/companies should intervene/"censor" the internet.

Given that today, social networking sites such as Facebook are being used to social engineer public opinion or to promote disinformation campaigns, just how much freedom should users have regarding their posted content? And wont any effort to filter user posts also amount to violating freedom of expression

Comment: Keep in mind that when you use private platforms such as YouTube and Facebook you accept their terms of use and freedom of expression doesn't apply.

Comment: @Cell Would you have applied that same logic in the south in the 1950s when African-Americans were not allowed to sit at lunch counters? Those were private businesses too. OR, would you prefer to have had Congress declare restaurants "public accommodations," required to treat people equally without regard to race, EVEN THOUGH they are privately owned? How would that apply today? Is it time for Congress to declare Twitter and Facebook public accommodations, or perhaps common carriers as the telecommunications companies are labelled?

Comment: @user4894 What you're saying doesn't make any sense. First you're comparing terms of use rules to racial discrimination. Not the same at all. Whether the blatant racism commited by a private entity is acceptable is up to the people/government to decide. Whether you got suspended from Twitter for violating the rules that you agreed upon when signing up is up to Twitter.  Even common carriers are allowed to refuse service if someone is breaking the rules. Just a month ago the bus driver refused a customer because he brought a firearm with him and that was prohibuted.

Comment: @Cell My remark was perfectly on point. Before the civil rights act of 1964, it was legal for a private company to discriminate by race. Afterwards, it wasn't. It's only a matter of time before Congress clarifies the legal status of viewpoint discrimination by social media.

Comment: @Cell I do not see a viewpoint neutral difference between what exactly is written into the terms of use, racism or speech restrictions. If private entities become sufficiently dominant in some type of social activity (dining or communication) they are no longer entitled to dictating its terms. Especially when such terms (are perceived to) go against communal values. Free speech is such a value, whether specific restrictions by social platforms do go against it is a separate issue, but they do not get out of it by simply citing private status. It has to be balanced with other concerns.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I would just note that we already have many forms of censorship, though not always called as such by custom. These include copyright violations, threats, media piracy, some racist speech, protections of "classified" information and corporate trade secrets, terrorist recruiting, publishing bomb-making instructions, some pornography, shouting fire in crowded theaters, hacking, etc. Moreover, in all spaces of "private property"  speech can be restricted. So free speech absolutism is a bit of a red herring.